# How to get specific elements in html string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So if I have a string of HTML, I was wondering how I would go about getting an array of parsed elements from that string that are of a certain class. For example, if I had a string that contained the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="c">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I get an array of all of the elements with a class of "b"? I have tried looking for a solution but I cannot find anything that works when the elements you are looking for are nested a couple layers.

Comment: You have the above code as your HTML and you want to grab them using jQuery. Right?

Comment: [document.querySelectorAll('.b')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put html inside `$()` and it will convert it into elements, of which you can then filter/find off of.

```js
var testStringOfHtml = `
<div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="c">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
`;

console.log($(testStringOfHtml).find('.b').get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var html = '<div><div class="a"><div class="b"></div> </div><div class="a"><div class="b"></div></div><div class="a"><div class="c"></div></div></div>';

var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = html;


var selectedB = el.querySelectorAll( '.b' ); 

console.log(selectedB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for `document.querySelectorAll`. Here is the MDN documentation so you can familiarize yourself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Here is an example of how to use it in your code:

```js
//use querySelectorAll method
var bElements = document.querySelectorAll('.b');

//you can iterate over and see all the elements
for (var i = 0; i < bElements.length; i++) {
  console.log(bElements[i]);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="c">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```